# Input user considered as method rather than just a common string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

I tried to make a simple program using python that take custom input from user and it would used into a list which have a input format like this.

```
$ python name_app.py
$ <method> <position_index> <value>
```

i have tried some thing like this.

```
 lst = []
 n = input().split()
 print(n[0])
 test = lst.n[0](n[1], n[2])
 print(test)
```

The sample input would be like:

```
$ python name_app.py
$ append 0 2
```

Well i thought the code would be like this if i pass the input

```
lst.append(0, 2)
```

But i got an error like below

```
File "app.py", line 5, in arr                                                                                                                 
    test = lst.n[0](n[1], n[2])                                                                                                                 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'n'
```

How could i make the user's input considered as "method" object and not a common attribute   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
test = getattr(lst, n[0])(n[1], n[2])
```

But then you're going to run into the problem that both `n[1]` and `n[2]` are strings, not ints.  So you'll need to pass them through [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to parse them.  Also, you probably won't be able to pass two arguments to the `list.append()` method, because it only takes one.

Finally, I think you may find the [`cmd` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#cmd-example) a more convenient way of converting user input into method calls, instead of using `getattr()` directly.

Comment: Thanks! i will wait for another answer before accepting this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr()` to call a method of `list`, or any module or class, from a user provided string.

```
lst = []   
n = input().split()
getattr(lst, n[0])(n[1])
print(lst)
```

Append the number 5 to the list like so:

```
$ python name_app.py
$ append 5
$ [5]
```